# Python: Indexing locations of a sub within a string

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will list the locations at which a sub-string occurs within a parent string. For example, say we search for "bc" within the parent string "abcabcabcabcabcabca" the program would return 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16.

So far I have been working with:

```
import string

def subStringMatchExact():
    print "This program will index the locations a given sequence"
    print "occurs within a larger sequence"
    seq = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search within: ")
    sub = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search for: ")
    n = 0
    for i in seq:
        x = string.find(seq, sub [n:])
        print x
        n = x + 1
```

I have also tried replacing string.find with string.index operator. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the [`.find()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) on the input string itself. It'll return a location for a match or `-1` if no match was found. It also takes a *start* parameter, so you can look for the *next* match:

```
def subStringMatchExact():
    print "This program will index the locations a given sequence"
    print "occurs within a larger sequence"
    seq = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search within: ")
    sub = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search for: ")

    positions = []
    pos = -1
    while True:
        pos = seq.find(sub, pos + 1)  # start searching *beyond* the previous match
        if pos == -1:   # Not found
            break
        positions.append(pos)
    return positions
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm lazy, so I'd use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abcabcabcabcabcabca"
>>> for m in re.finditer('bc',s):
...     print m.start()
... 
1
4
7
10
13
16
```

Comment: Curious, your numbers are off by one. Is your `s` defined as you say it is?

Comment: You cheater. :-) This is someone trying to learn string operations, so I gave them a string ops solution..

Comment: @unutbu: Different search string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Thanks.  I didn't realize I had used a different search string.  I was just assuming that OP was indexing incorrectly :X

Comment: @JoshCaswell -- Thanks for cleaning that up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are quite an elegant way, if that matters to you:

```
>>> seq = "abcabcabcabcabcabca"
>>> sub = "bc"
>>> [i for i in range(len(seq)) if seq[i:].startswith(sub)]
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16]
```

This should also be the fastest solution. It iterates through the string and tries to see if at any position the remaining string (from that position to the end) starts with the specified substring. If it does, it collects that position, if not it goes on to the next.

Comment: I'd expect this to be *slower*, because the `.find()` solution does its iteration in C instead. No time tonight to put that to the `timeit` test though.

Comment: You were right, I didn't consider the C implementation. With 100000 repetitions, mine took about three times as long as the `find()` solution posted above.